# DJI SDK: changing resolution of incoming video stream. Also, broken frames

Tags: java, dji-sdk

I receive raw H264 video through VideoFeeder from PrimaryVideoFeed and send it to DJICodecManager.
With DJI Phantom 4 YuvDataCallback receives correct video frames with HD (1280x720) resolution. With DJI Phantom 4 Advanced coupled with HDMI (Part 54) module it receives broken Full HD (1920x1080) video frames instead. Here's how it looks:

[image: broken video frame]

Speaking from image processing experience, such stuff happens when binary data isn't of the declared format, but that doesn't help much anyway.

So, two questions arise:

1. Is it possible to choose resolution of the incoming video stream? If so, how?
2. What exactly happens to the video frame with P4 Advanced? What's its actual format? How to fix it?

Here is the video stream initialization source code:

```
DJICodecManager  mCodecManager_ = new DJICodecManager(workContext, null, 0, 0, UsbAccessoryService.VideoStreamSource.Camera);
VideoFeeder.getInstance().getPrimaryVideoFeed().addVideoDataListener((bytes, size) ->  mCodecManager_.sendDataToDecoder(bytes, size));
mCodecManager_.enabledYuvData(true);
mCodecManager_.setYuvDataCallback(yuv_handler_);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, according to [this](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/issues/460), changing resolution for P4 Advanced is impossible - you simply can't do that. Got that message from official DJI support.

You'll find an answer for #2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090834/image-binary-interpretation-unknown-image-format/59139003#59139003).