# Image binary interpretation: unknown image format

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, rgb, dji-sdk

Let's say I've got an image of some format (its binary representation, say, cv::Mat from OpenCV or YuvImage from Android, not compressed), and interpreted its data as YUV NV21 (well, this was in example provided by DJI SDK, pretty much it). Here's what I've got:

[image: Broken frame]

From this, I assume that original format is NOT NV21. YUV2? RGB888? RGB32? Some other stuff?

How would one guess what's the original format of the binary data?

If that'll help, frame is taken from DJI drone stream.

Comment: Recommendation: interpret the data as Grayscale, and post the result as an image. Add information about the frame size in bytes, and the expected resolution. When reading as Grayscale, keep the original width, and set image height to size-in-bytes/width. (In case of NV21 for example, the Grayscale height is original_height*1.5)

Comment: Found the problem, and answered this question myself. Thanks for the comment, anyway :) Your insights helped to understand what was going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at the end, we've found some inconsistencies in image handling.

YuvImage of Android expects you to feed it with NV21, so I had a working conversion method from I420 to NV21. When I changed a video source (same vendor, different model), I expected it to come with the same format, but, in fact, it was NV12 instead.

*Reinterpret-casting* NV12 as I420 and then converting it to NV21 is what happened here.

Comment: Please could you put the source code?

Comment: @MohamadGhaithAlzin I'd really love to help... But I've left this job a year ago already. I'm not sure it's possible anymore :(

Answer (score 1):

The YUV image output uses an Android library which results in different YUV formats depending on the device used.

In my case, depending on which of the two devices I used, I needed to switch the bytes of the two color channels (NV12 to NV21).

What really helped me understanding which format I have was using the following YUV player:
https://github.com/Tee0125/yuvplayer

In the player you can actively change the way the data is interpreted as, just test different settings until you find the right one.

Although I don't know if you need it, I'll provide the method I used to switch the channels.

```
/**
 * Changes a NV12 yuv Frame to the NV21 format. Basically the two color channels are switched.
 *
 * @param yuvFrameNV12 The YUV Frame in the NV12 format.
 * @param width The width of the frame.
 * @param height The height of the frame.
 * @return The YUV Frame in the NV21 format.
 */
private static byte[] convertNV12toNV21(byte[] yuvFrameNV12, int width, int height) {
    final int length = yuvFrameNV12.length;
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < length; i1 += 2) {
        if (i1 >= width * height) { //start after the luminance bytes
            byte tmp = yuvFrameNV12[i1];
            yuvFrameNV12[i1] = yuvFrameNV12[i1+1];
            yuvFrameNV12[i1+1] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return yuvFrameNV12;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the end, I found the problem and answered this question myself. Though, some of your info was really useful (yuvplayer), so, get an upvote! :)