# rendering a cone in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am not sure how to render a cone in Qt. There is already a QConeMesh in Qt and I am following this documentation, but instead nothing is rendered.. I am pretty new to Qt, so I am probably making some kind of dumb mistake, but looking through it, I can't tell where I have gone wrong. It does render other stuff, like lines, so I'm pretty sure the problem is in here.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include "Boid.h"
#include <qdebug.h>

Boid::Boid(QNode *parent)
  : QEntity(parent),
  m_Position(0, 0, 0),
  m_MovementVector(rand() % 2 - 1, rand() % 2 - 1, rand() % 2 - 1),
  m_BoidColor(15, 100, 100)
{
  Qt3DExtras::QConeMesh *boidCone = new Qt3DExtras::QConeMesh();
  boidCone->setBottomRadius(0.5f);
  boidCone->setTopRadius(0.01f);
  boidCone->setHasTopEndcap(true);
  boidCone->setHasBottomEndcap(true);
  boidCone->setSlices(100);
  boidCone->setLength(1);
  boidCone->setRings(100);

  Qt3DCore::QTransform *boidTransform = new Qt3DCore::QTransform();
  boidTransform->setScale(1);
  boidTransform->setTranslation(m_Position);
  boidTransform->setRotation(QQuaternion::fromAxisAndAngle(QVector3D(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), 25.0f));

  Qt3DRender::QMaterial *boidMaterial = new Qt3DRender::QMaterial();
  boidMaterial->setEnabled(true);

  qDebug() << "test " << parent;
  Qt3DCore::QEntity *boidEntity = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(parent);
  boidEntity->addComponent(boidCone);
  boidEntity->addComponent(boidTransform);
  boidEntity->addComponent(boidMaterial);
}
```

the debug will print out test and the correct parent object.
Here is the documentation I am following, I think it is slightly out of date
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.6/qt3d-basicshapes-cpp-example.html

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, figured it out.. had to use QPhongMaterial, but it was moved to Qt3DExtras in the new version.

That is, adding a Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial to the QEntity

Comment: When you answer your own question, it is a good practice to 1) accept it, 2) write an explanation on what you've done to fix the problem, so that people that find that question would be able to do the same thing. Here is a good example of such an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090834/image-binary-interpretation-unknown-image-format